# Optional Stopping Theorem (continuous case) where stopping time is unbounded

Tags: martingales, stopping-times

I am referring to the version of OST that states that: when M is a continuous Martingale and $\rho \leq \tau $ are bounded stopping times then $M_\infty := lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} M_t $ exists almost surely and $ M_{\infty} \in L^1 $.

Now I am looking for an example when we have an *unbounded* stopping time and the result of the theorem fails. I've tried the exponential martingale $ M_t := exp(B_t -\frac{t}{2})$ where $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion then considered the stopping time $ \tau := inf ${t $\geq$ 0 : $M_t = 2 $} which is unbounded but I couldn't see a contradiction to the theorem. Am I missing something or is there another example (also I would be interested to see other examples even if this does work out)

Comment: Can you please check the statement of the OST? There is something missing/wrong (for a continuous martingale $M$ the limit $\lim_{t \to \infty} M_t$ need not exist, consider e.g. Brownian motion).

Comment: Ah yea the other condition is $ \mathbb{E} (M_{\tau} | \mathscr{F}_{\rho}) = M_{\rho} $ for $ \rho \leq \tau $ as given above

Comment: If you would take your time to state the question properly, then it would be more likely that somebody is willing to spend his/her time to answer your question.

Comment: Yea you're right - I should of double checked the statement of the Optional Stopping Theorem in this case. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to edit my post so would you be able to give me any pointers on my Query (which I still can't figure out). Would really appreciate it as someone who is interested in learning more about stochastic calculus and related topics

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$
M_t\xrightarrow[t\to+\infty]{\mathbb{P}\rm -a.s.} 0
$$
which makes Doob's theorem to work for the stopped martingale $\left(M_t^\tau\right)_{t\ge0}$.